# Points from one camera system to another

Tags: java, opencv, math, triangulation

I have a camera which takes two pictures of the same scene from a slightly different position and orientation.

For my SfM approach I am doing the essential decomposition which works perfectly as I am getting the 4 possible solutions for the relative camera pose.  I assume that the first camera is located at the origin of the world-space.

The problem is when I try to find the correct combination of R1/R2 and T1/T2. My idea is that I triangulate all good matches found before. This will give me a list of points (x,y,z,w) in the world space / first-camera-space.

Now I want to transform a copy of this point into the system of the 2nd image and check if the z-value of the original point and the copied-transformed-Point are positive. If this happens for most of the points, the used combination of R and T is the correct one, but it still finds the wrong combination as the rectification produces wrong results (from hardcoding and testing I know that R2 and T2 are correct, but it finds R1 and T2)

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Transforms the given point into the target camera system 
 * and returns the z value
 * @param point Point to transform
 * @param system Camera system to transform to
 * @return double z value
 */
private Mat transformPointIntoSystem(Mat point, Mat system){
    double[] vals = {point.get(0, 0)[0], point.get(1, 0)[0] ,point.get(2, 0)[0] ,1};
    Mat point_homo = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32F);
    point_homo.put(0, 0, vals);

    Mat dst = new Mat(3,4,CvType.CV_32F);
    // Multiply the matrix * vector
    Core.gemm(system, point_homo, 1, dst, 0, dst);

    return dst; 
}

 private void findCorrectRT(Mat R1, Mat R2, Mat T1, Mat T2, Mat R, Mat T, MatOfPoint2f objLeft, MatOfPoint2f objRight){
    Mat res = new Mat(); // Result mat for triangulation

    Mat P1 = new Mat(4,4,CvType.CV_32F);
    double[] diagVal = {1,0,0,0,
                        0,1,0,0,
                        0,0,1,0};       
    P1.put(0, 0, diagVal);


    int[] max = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < max.length; i++)
        max[i] = 0;

    Mat P2 = buildCameraMatrix(R1, T1);     
    Calib3d.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, objLeft, objRight, res);      
    publishProgress(res.size().width + " , " + res.size().height);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size().width; i++){
        Mat X1 = transformPointIntoSystem(res.col(i), P1);
        Mat X2 = transformPointIntoSystem(X1, P2);

        if(X1.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0 && X2.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0){
            max[0] += 1;
        }
    }

    P2 = buildCameraMatrix(R1, T2);     
    Calib3d.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, objLeft, objRight, res);      
    publishProgress(res.size().width + " , " + res.size().height);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size().width; i++){
        Mat X1 = transformPointIntoSystem(res.col(i), P1);
        Mat X2 = transformPointIntoSystem(X1, P2);

        if(X1.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0 && X2.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0){
            max[1] += 1;
        }
    }

    P2 = buildCameraMatrix(R2, T1);     
    Calib3d.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, objLeft, objRight, res);      
    publishProgress(res.size().width + " , " + res.size().height);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size().width; i++){
        Mat X1 = transformPointIntoSystem(res.col(i), P1);
        Mat X2 = transformPointIntoSystem(X1, P2);

        if(X1.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0 && X2.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0){
            max[2] += 1;
        }
    }

    P2 = buildCameraMatrix(R2, T2);     
    Calib3d.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, objLeft, objRight, res);      
    publishProgress(res.size().width + " , " + res.size().height);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size().width; i++){
        Mat X1 = transformPointIntoSystem(res.col(i), P1);
        Mat X2 = transformPointIntoSystem(X1, P2);

        if(X1.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0 && X2.get(2, 0)[0] >= 0){
            max[3] += 1;
        }
    }


    // find the index of the maximal value in this array
    int largest = max[0], index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < max.length; i++) {
      if ( max[i] >= largest ) {
          largest = max[i];
          index = i;
       }
    }

    switch(index){
    case 0: // R1 T1    
        publishProgress("R1 and T1");
        R1.copyTo(R);
        T1.copyTo(T);
        break;

    case 1: // R1 T2
        publishProgress("R1 and T2");
        R1.copyTo(R);
        T2.copyTo(T);
        break;

    case 2: // R2 T1
        publishProgress("R2 and T1");
        R2.copyTo(R);
        T1.copyTo(T);
        break;

    case 3: // R2 T2
        publishProgress("R2 and T2");
        R2.copyTo(R);
        T2.copyTo(T);
        break;
    }

}
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your logic. The triangulated points would be in the world coordinate space. The world coordinate space has an origin at the center of P1. The estimated camera P2 is in the same coordinate space, so wouldn't the triangulated points already be in the same space as P2?

Comment: The idea is, that I can check if the point is in front of both kameras. The z-axis of each camera is the view direction. The cameras can be arbitrary rotated to each other. So I transform the point from one system to the 2nd and can check if the point is in the visible area of the 2nd camera by checking if the z value is still positive.